# Preprocess R script in real time before loading it

Tags: r

I would like to preprocess the source of an R script before the loader loads it and executes it. Essentially, I am looking for some way to create a hook so that `library(some_library)` will call that hook with the unparsed contents of `some_library` and let the hook do the rest of the job.
This will allow me to parse R code in an ad hoc manner, possibly rearrange it, and then let the R interpreter execute the processed code.

Comment: Have you looked through ?.onLoad or ?.onAttach ? Perhaps they can help.

Comment: @MarkeD I did see that, but these hooks will only run after the script is already parsed. Else, how will the interpreter know if .onLoad or .onAttach is present in that script? I would like to attach a handler for any script/library imports (without adding functions to the imported libraries), and this handler should take care of parsing and then loading the code.

Comment: What is it that you _really_ want to do?  R is an interpreter; you don't need another preprocessor.  If you have performance concerns, start by profiling.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Its not about performance. Lets say I have some ad hoc extensions to R Grammar and I have a package capable of understanding and processing these extensions, I would want this package to interpose on the the R loader and take care of parsing and restructuring the code so that it can be executed by the R interpreter.